# Resetting a Formly form within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have an Angular Formly form inside an ng-repeat. I've got everything working as I would expect except for the reset button. For some reason clicking any reset button always resets the last form, not the one it's supposed to. Submitting and updateInitialValue() seem to work fine.

```
<div ng-repeat="model in vm.models">
```

Here is the form declaration inside the repeat:

```
<formly-form model="model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options[$index]" form="vm.form[$index]">
```

And here is the reset button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.options[$index].resetModel()">Reset</button>
```

Here is the whole thing in a fiddle.

http://jsbin.com/feguvulumo/edit?html,js,output

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out with some help from @kentcdodds on the Formly gitter chat (https://gitter.im/formly-js/angular-formly)

He suggested that the issue was that the repeating forms are sharing the same field configuration.

To fix it, I implemented a function that was called by an ng-init inside the ng-repeat. It builds up an array of fields objects as it loops.

```
function addFields() {
  vm.fields.push(new getFields());
}
```

I then changed the fields property on the `<formly-form>` like so

```
<formly-form model="model" fields="vm.fields[$index]" options="vm.options[$index]" form="vm.form[$index]">
```

Full solution
http://jsbin.com/yanopeyija/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to angular, but generally this could be achieved if we change the button type as reset :

```
<button type="reset" >
```